# Web part to Display list data across sites and subsites - SP 2013

Tags: content-query-web-part, data-view-web-part

I have been looking at some add-on third party providers like :

[Lightning Tools](http://lightningtools.com/products/lightning-conductor-web-part-2013/)

[Boost Solutions](http://www.boostsolutions.com/listcollection.html)

[Bamboo Solutions](http://store.bamboosolutions.com/c-18-data-management.aspx)

looking for any tips or advices to which one best works well and easy to use as what i really need is to be able to show a list on another site using a webpart easily plus the possibility to filter,sort etc...

I know i can use CQWP but its a bit of configuration to get it to that point.

if there is any solution that exist in codeplex that would be great

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I've had first hand experience with LC from LT and it works well. I've had nothing but horror with anything from Bamboo, never tried anything from Boost.